# Adding scheduled items to multi-slot crafting queue

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android game.

Areas in the game have crafting slots which determine how many items can be crafted at once. If there are no slots available, the item is given a scheduled start date which correlates to when a slot will become available.

The problem I'm encountering is that the current code only considers when the first slot will become available, not when any slot will.

Adding scheduled item:

```
long timeSlotAvailable = getTimeSlotAvailable(location);

Pending_Inventory newScheduledItem = new Pending_Inventory(itemId, state, timeSlotAvailable, quantity, craftTime, location);
```

Getting the time a slot is available:

```
public static long getTimeSlotAvailable(Long location) {
    List<Pending_Inventory> pendingItems = getPendingItems(location, true);
    int locationSlots = Slot.getUnlockedSlots(location);
    long timeAvailable = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Works for single slots, not for multi though. Needs to consider slot count.
    for (Pending_Inventory pending_inventory : pendingItems) {
        long finishTime = pending_inventory.getTimeCreated() + pending_inventory.getCraftTime();
        if (finishTime > timeAvailable) {
            timeAvailable = finishTime;
        }
    }

    return timeAvailable;
}
```

The code works by looking through every item currently being crafted or scheduled to craft, and getting the time the last one finishes.

`locationSlots` is currently unused, but I believe it will be required to calculate the correct time a slot will be available.

I've tried a few approaches (adding all finish times to an array & getting the n value showed promise, but I couldn't get my head around it), but am all out of ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually took another go at the array approach, and succeeded.

```
public static long getTimeSlotAvailable(Long location) {
    List<Pending_Inventory> pendingItems = getPendingItems(location, true);
    int numSlots = Slot.getUnlockedSlots(location);

    // Add all of the times a slot will become available to a list
    List<Long> finishTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Pending_Inventory pending_inventory : pendingItems) {
        long finishTime = pending_inventory.getTimeCreated() + pending_inventory.getCraftTime();
         finishTimes.add(finishTime);
    }

    // Sort these times so the latest time is first
    Collections.sort(finishTimes, Collections.<Long>reverseOrder());

    if (finishTimes.size() >= numSlots) {
        // If we're all full up, get the first time a slot will become available
        return finishTimes.get(numSlots-1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, it can go in now
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone in the future with a similar problem.